# IOS UIButton with IBAction

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have create some buttons on for loop on below code.

```
UIView *buttonsView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, _viewEmoji.frame.size.width, 35)];
    [buttonsView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
for (int i = 0; i < myObject.count; i ++) {
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [button setFrame:CGRectMake(35*i + 5, 0, 35, 35)];
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [myObject objectAtIndex:i]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(clickButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [buttonsView addSubview:button];
    }
```

And now, How to I can click button to handle event.

Every button was clicked, It will handle 1 event.

Ex: if I have 2 buttons was created by for loop. When I click button 1, it's will log 1, When I click button 2, it's will log 2.

Comment: Give each button a unique `tag` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like

```
UIView *buttonsView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, _viewEmoji.frame.size.width, 35)];
[buttonsView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
for (int i = 0; i < myObject.count; i ++) {
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(35*i + 5, 0, 35, 35)];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [myObject objectAtIndex:i]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(clickButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    // set the tag for identify which button you pressed
     button.tag = i; // else use -->  [myObject objectAtIndex:i]
    [buttonsView addSubview:button];
}

  //here add your buttonsView to mainview
self.view addsubview(buttonsView)

// for button action
-(void)clickButton:(UIButton*)sender
{
   NSLog(@" Index: %d ", sender.tag);
   [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"XXX.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Comment: I'd suggest setting each button's tag to `i + 1` or some other calculation that avoids giving a button a tag of `0`.

Comment: Oh my god! It's very sample. Thanks.

Comment: simple bro , **sender** is your current selected button you can do anything for your selected button, thats all

Comment: You can download demo my function on this link:
https://github.com/VMTrinh/StickerSmall

Comment: Currently, I'm working Sticker function same Viber. Do you know Viber?

Comment: @IOSDeveloper Don't ask completely new questions in the comments. If you have a new question, post a new question.

Comment: OK! This is my question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33536842/ios-uipagecontrol-to-do-stickers

Comment: My new question, please help me!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33561266/ios-uicollectionview-with-scrollview