# IOS UICollectionView with ScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have 6 images in my database.

I have created `UIScrollView *scroll;`, after that, I had created `UICollectionView` and added `UICollectionView` to `UIScrollView`

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
        collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(screenWidth*i,5,screenWidth ,self.scroll.frame.size.height-5) collectionViewLayout:layout];
        [collectionView setDataSource:self];
        [collectionView setDelegate:self];
        [collectionView setPagingEnabled:YES];
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
        collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
        [collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
        [collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
        [self.scroll addSubview:collectionView];
```

And now, when scroll I want reload data of `UICollectionView` on below this code:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
    if (!pageControlBeingUsed) {
        [getAllEmoji removeAllObjects];
        // Switch the indicator when more than 50% of the previous/next page is visible
        CGFloat pageWidth = self.scroll.frame.size.width;
        int page = floor((self.scroll.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 3) / pageWidth) + 1;
        self.pageControl.currentPage = page;
        //Change Emoji when scroll
        NSString *str = [getAllCategory objectAtIndex:page];
        NSArray *arr = [Emoji MR_findByAttribute:@"category" withValue:str];
        if (arr.count > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.count; i++) {
                Emoji *emoji = [arr objectAtIndex:i];
                [getAllEmoji addObject:emoji.name_emoji];
            }
            [collectionView reloadData];
        }
    }
}
```

first pageControl is 2 images.

When I scroll to second pageControl is 2 images(But, it's don't load new image).

When I scroll to third pageControl is 2 images(it's load new image).

You can see some images in my project on below link:
http://imgur.com/a/nIMic

And my project demo.
https://github.com/VMTrinh/Sticker

Please help me!

Comment: what the problem u faced ..

Comment: First, When I scroll firstly, it's not reload collectionView to show new image. In my image array have 2 new images. You can download my demo project to check this error!\

Comment: I know reason for my problem, but I cannot resolve it.

Comment: Can you help me, if you know reason for my problem

Comment: Link to new question for my problem!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33562705/create-multi-uicollectionview-in-a-viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is that you don't need to embed collection view in a scroll view.

The scroll mechanism is managed by the collection view.

You can scroll your collection with the `scrollToItemAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: Can you see my some images about my problem!

Comment: My problem is detail in here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33562705/create-multi-uicollectionview-in-a-viewcontroller