# Create Multi UICollectionView in a ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

Title is my problem.

I had created `UICollectionView` in `for loop`. So, it's created some `UICollectionView`

My code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < getAllCategory.count; i ++) {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.scroll.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.scroll.frame.size;

        UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
        collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(screenWidth*i,5,screenWidth ,self.scroll.frame.size.height-5) collectionViewLayout:layout];
        [collectionView setDataSource:self];
        [collectionView setDelegate:self];
        [collectionView setPagingEnabled:YES];
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
        collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
        [collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
        [collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
        [self.scroll addSubview:collectionView];
    }
```

So, When I scroll to new UICollectionView to show new image, it's not show new image. Because, it's reload data for last UICollectionView.

My code when show new image.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
    if (!pageControlBeingUsed) {
        [getAllEmoji removeAllObjects];
        // Switch the indicator when more than 50% of the previous/next page is visible
        CGFloat pageWidth = self.scroll.frame.size.width;
        int page = floor((self.scroll.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
        self.pageControl.currentPage = page;
        //Change Emoji when scroll
        NSString *str = [getAllCategory objectAtIndex:page];
        NSArray *arr = [Emoji MR_findByAttribute:@"category" withValue:str];
        if (arr.count > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.count; i++) {
                Emoji *emoji = [arr objectAtIndex:i];
                [getAllEmoji addObject:emoji.name_emoji];
            }
            [collectionView reloadData];
        }
    }
}
```

So, it's only show old image for all `UICollectionView`, it's only change image for last `UICollectionView`

How to I can resolve this problem.

Here is link to you see some images my problem
http://imgur.com/a/nIMic

Please help me!

************************** I had resolved my problem *******************

Comment: It is not very clear - If you create several collection views, you should store them in an array.

From what I see, you only have access to the last created collectionView, stored in your collectionView variable.

Comment: Can you help me resolve this problem

Comment: Because, I'm working Emotions function, So, I have to create uicollectionView

Comment: If you can help me!
You can see my project in here, Tks
https://github.com/VMTrinh/Sticker

Comment: You can get the Collection View in the 'scrollViewDidScroll' method by doing a collectionView = ((UIScrollView*)sender).subviews[0]; before you reload data. But the whole thing looks a bit twisted. You'd better create a custom collection view ( MyCategoryCollectionView) object that deals with your data for one category. Ensure it works, then create several instances of this class for each category.

Comment: How to I can reload collectionView

Comment: Your reloadData is the right way…

Comment: When I reloadData follow old way, it's wrong! Because, it's cannot get uicollectionview currently. Can you help me reloaddata right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add code

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *collectionArray;

self.collectionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; 

[self.collectionArray addObject:collectionView];

[self.collectionArray[page] reloadData];
```

Comment: I suggest you use a collectionView with 3 sections

Comment: I resolved. Add code  `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *collectionArray; `  `self.collectionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];' ` ` [self.scroll addSubview:collectionView];
        
        [self.collectionArray addObject:collectionView];`            `[self.collectionArray[page] reloadData];
            
//            [collectionView reloadData];`

Comment: Thank you for your help! I had resolved since 14 minutes.

Comment: Now, my problem is some buttons in my project

Comment: I have new problem, Can you help me?

Comment: New question. You can use old source code. Please help me! Thanks.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33569022/ios-handle-event-click-multi-button

Answer (score 0):

Your code just handles a `collectionView` (the last collection).

You should create a property to hold these `collectionView`: `NSMutableArray * arrCollectionView`

```
       for (int i = 0; i < getAllCategory.count; i ++) {
            CGRect frame;
            frame.origin.x = self.scroll.frame.size.width * i;
            frame.origin.y = 0;
            frame.size = self.scroll.frame.size;

            UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
            UICollectionView * collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(screenWidth*i,5,screenWidth ,self.scroll.frame.size.height-5) collectionViewLayout:layout];
            [collectionView setDataSource:self];
            [collectionView setDelegate:self];
            [collectionView setPagingEnabled:YES];
            collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
            collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
            [collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
            [collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
            [self.scroll addSubview:collectionView];

            [arrCollectionView addObject: collectionView];
     }
```

Then in `scrollViewDidScroll`

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
    if (!pageControlBeingUsed) {
        [getAllEmoji removeAllObjects];
        // Switch the indicator when more than 50% of the previous/next page is visible
        CGFloat pageWidth = self.scroll.frame.size.width;
        int page = floor((self.scroll.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
        self.pageControl.currentPage = page;
        //Change Emoji when scroll
        NSString *str = [getAllCategory objectAtIndex:page];
        NSArray *arr = [Emoji MR_findByAttribute:@"category" withValue:str];
        if (arr.count > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.count; i++) {
                Emoji *emoji = [arr objectAtIndex:i];
                [getAllEmoji addObject:emoji.name_emoji];
            }

            //[collectionView reloadData];
            for (UICollectionView * collectionView in arrCollectionView) {
                if (collectionView == sender) {
                     [collectionView reloadData];
                     break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not reload data
for (UICollectionView * collectionViewa in arrCollectionView) {
                if (collectionViewa == sender) {
                    [collectionViewa reloadData];
                    break;
                }
            }

Comment: @IOSDeveloper updated my answer. Please try `sender.subviews[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Please thinking your design model, you can separate the UICollectionView in different Class, every pointer to object by self, create different array and datasource for load.

Comment: Can you download my project and help me some codes?